# JQM preventing default link action w/ download attribute

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

Jquery Mobile seems to messing around with the native browser click event of my links when I don't want it to.

Here's my simple code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>  <!-- version 1.11.1 -->
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/oldname.txt" download='newname.txt'>Download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This should cause the browser to present "newname.txt" to me for download, but it fails.

However if comment out the jquery.mobile script line, the link works fine.

(Note: This is not a CORS problem, as the link is relative).

What gives?

EDIT:

If I had the following to the page:

```
<script>
$("a")[0].click(); 
</script>
```

Then, I successfully get a download prompt of "newname.txt" from the browser.

But, again, if I click on it, I just get redirected to the old filename.

Comment: I added "<!DOCTYPE HTML>" to the top, but there was no change. =(

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I have made the anchor part of a control group and every time that I click on it a new page widget is created with the data-url set to the href.  Can't figure out how to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

download attribute is of html5 and you have not defined the doctype and that's the key problem you are having:

Replace this:

```
<html>
```

with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I tried both combinations of <html> <!DOCTYPE html>, but still not working. =( Sniff.

Comment: without both, the link gets displayed directly in the browser without presenting a download option to the user.

Comment: I only get a download option of "newname.txt" if both html tags are listed *and* jquerymobile is removed from the script line. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
You need to include the data-ajax=false attribute in your anchor.

```
<a href="/oldname.txt" download='newname.txt' data-ajax=false>Download</a>
```